# H2o random forest plot on r

Tags: r, random-forest, h2o

I'm new to `h2o` and I'm having difficulty with this package on r.
I'm using a traning and test set 5100 and 2300 obs respectively with 18917 variables and a binary target (0,1) 
I ran a random forest:

```
train_h20<-as.h2o(train)
test_h20<-as.h2o(test)

forest <- h2o.randomForest(x = Words,
                           y = 18918,
                           training_frame = train_h20,
                           ntree = 250,
                           validation = test_h20,
                           seed = 8675309)
```

I know i can get the plot of logloss or mse or ... as the number of tree changes
But is there a way to plot an image of the model itself. I mean the final ensembled tree used for the final predictions?

Also, another question, in `randomForest` package I could use `varImp` function which returned me, as well as the absolute importance, the class-specific measures (computed as mean decrease in accuracy), i interpreted as a class-relative measure of variable importance.

varImp matrix, randomForest package:

[image: varImp matrix, randomForest package]
In `h2o` package I only find the absolute importance measure, is there something similar?

Comment: Best to ask your two questions as two questions. (See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/39224/167713 for why.)
There is no random forest plot for H2O; I've seen the advice to read the raw POJO output! (Either way, for anything but a toy model you are not going to want to do this.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no a final tree at the end of the random forest in R with randomForest packages. To make final predıction, random forest uses voting method. Voting means, for any data:
For example 0;

## of tree that predict the data as Class 0/total number of trees in the forest

For Class 1 it is same as the Class 0;

## of tree that predict the data as Class 1/total number of trees in the forest

However you can use ctree.
library("party")
x <- ctree(Class ~ ., data=data)
plot(x)